# Transforming my Counter tuple results (from counter) into string

Tags: string, counter, text-mining, spacy

I'm trying to store my Counter results in a different way than default (preferably with spacy library) . For this case i need the results to be Word,value + the next separated by a new line. Right now i have the results as tuples ('word' : value).

I've tried storing the results from the counter into string by using str() and by using the join function. However, i end up with all word characters on a newline.

```
freqtab = Counter(nout)

freqtab2 = freqtab.most_common()
```

Where nout is the list with words. So here i got the right results stored from most common to least common (which is what I want but not in the right format)

So instead of getting `('Elephant', 12), ('Orca', 9), ('Seal', 2)`, I want:

```
Elephant,12
Orca,9
Seal,2
```

Comment: `for wrd,freq in freqtab2:
 print("{},{}".format(wrd, freq))`? See https://ideone.com/EaYYKe

Comment: Thanks! This code is working like i want but can you tell me how to store this output in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the data from the list of tuples joined in a single multiline string you may use

```
freqtab2 = [('Elephant', 12), ('Orca', 9), ('Seal', 2)]
result = "\n".join(["{},{}".format(wrd, freq) for wrd,freq in freqtab2])
print(result)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NBoYr8).

The list comprehension `["{},{}".format(wrd, freq) for wrd,freq in freqtab2]` re-formats the `freqtab2` list of tuples into a list of strings, and `"\n".join(...)` makes a single multiline string out of it.